# How to cancel queued recurring a hangfire job if it has a previous active running job?

Tags: c#, hangfire

We have Hangfire job for downlading external files, the job recurring interval = 5 min.
Sometime job can take longer than a 5 min. So we need to cancel next queued job if it has active running job

We tried add `DisableConcurrentExecution` to prevent next job

```
[DisableConcurrentExecution(60)]
public void Execute(){...}
```

But it just prevents the job from running for a while, after which it throws a timeout exception:

> Hangfire.Storage.DistributedLockTimeoutException: Timeout expired. The timeout elapsed prior to obtaining a distributed lock on the 'xxx' resource.
> at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerDistributedLock.Acquire(IDbConnection connection, String resource, TimeSpan timeout)

So, we don't need any error logs, just want to cancel job from executing

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38563265/2892829) answer your question?

Comment: @Orifjon thanks, it helped me to understand state cases, so in any case we need to change job state to failed or success. But is there any easier way to cancel job?

Comment: You can just delete it.